# The tangent bundle and dual tangent bundle in topos theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, deformation-theory, infinity-topos-theory

Let $\mathcal B = B \mathbb T$ be an $\infty$-topos, thought of as the classifying $\infty$-topos of some "$\infty$-geometric theory" $\mathbb T$. The notion of "$\infty$-geometric theory" is not defined in general, but for example, if $\mathcal B$ is a sheaf topos on a site $(\mathcal C, J)$, then $\mathbb T$ would be "the theory of a flat, cover-preserving functor out of $\mathcal C$." Then there seem to be two different $\infty$-topoi over $\mathcal B$ which are each in some sense "tangent bundles" of $\mathcal B$:

1. On the one hand, there is the [tangent $\infty$-topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tangent+%28infinity%2C1%29-category) $T\mathcal B \to \mathcal B$, whose fiber over $B \in \mathcal B$ is the category of spectrum objects in $\mathcal B_{/B}$.
2. On the other hand, there is the "classifying topos for spectrum objects in $\mathbb T$-structures", $B(T\mathbb T) \to B \mathbb T$. By this I mean the $\infty$-topos such than an $\mathcal X$-point of $B(T \mathbb T)$ comprises an $\mathcal X$-point $M$ of $\mathcal B$, and a spectrum object in $Pts_{\mathcal X}(\mathcal B)_{/M}$.

(1) seems to be what is discussed more commonly when talking about Goodwillie calculus and $\infty$-topoi. But it seems to me that (2) should be equally important. For instance, when $\mathcal B = B(CRing) = Fun(CRing_\omega, Spaces)$ is the classifying topos for commutative rings, so that a point of $\mathcal B$ is a commutative ring object, then $B(T(CRing)) = B(Mod)$ is the classifying topos for (ring, module) pairs. This will tie in with the deformation- theoretic uses of the tangent category formalism. Whereas the tangent topos $T(B(CRing))$ in the sense of (1) looks rather bizarre to me.

**Question 1:** What relationship, if any, is there between the "tangent topos" in the sense of (1) and the "tangent topos" in the sense of (2)?

**Question 2:** Do (1) and (2) each have some (possibly distinct) roles to play in $\infty$-topos theory?

**Question 3:** Is there a good way to construct $B(T \mathbb T)$ in general?

Note that (1) and (2) are each applying the same "tangent category" formalism to topos theory. But (1) applies it to the underlying logos of the $\infty$-topos, whereas (2) applies it thinking of the category of points as the "underlying category" of an $\infty$-topos, instead of the logos.

Comment: Interesting question, is it clear that they are *different* ? (I haven't thought about it at all)

Comment: (from thinking about it a little bit, it doesn't sound preposterous that they should be the same)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Hmmm.... If $\mathcal B = Psh(C)$ is a presheaf topos, then the fiber of $T\mathcal B$ over $F \in \mathcal B$ is $Fun(Elts(F)^{op},Spectra)$. On the other hand, if $\mathcal B = BObj = Psh(Spaces_\omega^{op})$, then $BTObj \to BObj$ is the fully faithful inclusion of the excisive functors. If $F = \ast \in BObj$ is the terminal presheaf, then the fiber $B(TObj)_\ast$ is the category of spectral presheaves on $Spaces_\omega^{op}$, whereas the fiber $T(BObj)_\ast$ is empty (the identity functor is not excisive). So it seems the constructions really are different.

Comment: I think they're also different for $\mathcal B = BCRing$. On the one hand, $B(TCRing) = BMod$ knows something about _loops_ in the category of points $CRing$. Whereas on the other hand, $TBCRing$ knows about loops in $BCRing$ and in particular about _suspension_ in $CRing_\omega$ (which is carried to loops by the Yoneda embedding $CRing_\omega^{op} \to BCRing$). So the two constructions seem to be related to _dual_ information about commutative rings.

Comment: I'm confused by your first example, the fiber can't be empty - the category of elements of the final functor is just the category you're taking presheaves on so the fiber of $T(Bobj)$ at $*$ should also be spectral presheaves, shouldn't it ?. Here's how I view the relation between the two : $Fun^R(Y, Exc(S^\omega, X))\simeq Exc(S^\omega, Fun^R(Y,X))$, and $Fun_*(Y, TX)$ is a full subcategory of the former, while the category that should be classified by your version (2) is a full subcategory of the latter. (1/2)

Comment: It might very well be that they are different, but at first sight it seems like a comparison could be made (2/2)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I agree that $T(BObj)_\ast = Psh_{Spt}(Spaces_\omega^{op})$ -- it's $(BTObj)_\ast$ which I'm saying is empty -- it's the collection of excisive structures on the identity functor $Spaces_\omega \to Spaces$. And note that the category of points $Pts_Y(X)$ is a full subcategory of $Fun^R(Y,X)^{op}$, not of $Fun^R(Y,X)$. So we're comparing a full subcategory of $Fun^R(Exc(S^\omega, X))^{op}$ and a full subcategory of $Exc(S^\omega, Fun^R(Y,X)^{op})$, so the excisive condition is indeed being applied in opposite categories. So I think the comparison is not so clear.

Comment: Oh so it was a typo, ok ! I also hadn't realized this op thing, it makes it clearer now, thanks :)